# Restrict S3 sub-folder level bucket policy about private and public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have a lot of information that we can make our bucket to public and private by bucket level. But I'm curious that we can make bucket policy to folder level even to sub-folders. Following is folder structure in my current S3 bucket.

```
companies/aa-company/public-folder
companies/aa-company/private-folder
companies/bb-company/public-folder
companies/bb-company/private-folder
```

What I want to know is I want to make **Public Read Access** to **public-folder** in bucket policy. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, by means of [wildcards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html):

> You can use wildcards as part of the resource ARN. You can use wildcard characters (* and ?) within any ARN segment (the parts separated by colons). An **asterisk (*) represents any combination of zero or more characters**, and a question mark (?) represents any single character. You can use multiple * or ? characters in each segment, but a wildcard cannot span segments

**Example policy** can look as follows (based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-342-d/*/public-folder/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You will also need to disable block **public access settings** on the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely possible. You can use [wildcards](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html#s3-arn-examples) to achieve this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/companies/aa-company/public-folder*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/companies/bb-company/public-folder*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```